# Excel Hierarchy Formula

Tags: excel, formula, hierarchy

I've got a list of bill-of-materials information that I'm trying to parse. It's really long, so I'd rather not do it manually.

Here's a sample table much like what I'm working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2559htsejx6nub/excel%20hierarchy.PNG
[image]

A part with a level of .2 is under the next highest .1, .3 under .2, and so on. Assume I already have Col A and Col B, and am trying to generate Col C. For any .2 or .3 row that has "yes" listed in column B, I want to have "yes" listed in Col C for the next row above which has a .1 in Col A.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Removed answer as I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following formula in cell `C2` and drag down to the rest of column C:

```
=IF(A2=0.1,IF(OR(AND(A3=0.2,B3="Yes"),AND(A4=0.3,B4="yes")),"Yes", "No"),"")
```

Result:

[image]

As far as I can tell this is exactly what you were asking for.